# Java - Setting session variable group_concat_max_len in MySqlDataSource

Tags: java, mysql, datasource

I'm searching for a way to set the group_concat_max_len variable for the session of a MySQL connection. The MySQL Connection is created by a MySQL datasource.

Currently I set this variable bei running a statement first:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = ?
```

I don't want to run this statement before every other statement (because it isn't always needed) and if it's needed, you may forget it.
So I guess it would be nice to add this as a parameter when creating the MySQL datasource.
I can't find any set-method for setting the group_concat_max_len variable in the MysqlDataSource class, but there is a setSessionVariables method, which may be the way to set it. But I don't know how to use it, because it's only taking one string parameter. And I even can't find any doumentation for it.

Does anyone know how to set the group_concat_max_len variable in a MysqlDataSource?

Comment: What about setting this value at Database Server level in mysql global configuration

Comment: I fine tune this inside the stored proc I am calling. Only needed on about 5% or less of them